# Sql query times out. But, after renaming any index it works

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

We have this query, that worked during years.

A few months ago it started giving timeouts.

However, if we rename an index (adding some character to its name) and run the query again, it works. Day after day we have to do the same. Every day we rename an index, then the query works again.

What's the problem? How can we solve this issue? How does renaming an index solve the time out problem?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more information: table structures, index declaration, table statistics, the problem query

Comment: The question is, why renaming an index can affect the time out of a query. It's actually a stored procedure we are running (1000 lines long)

Comment: My guess? Your index is not performing well and the query plan is getting cached. Since you rename the index, the plan is most likely changed for the next time you run the query. Then cached again for the next run. Have you tried troubleshooting with RECOMPILE or looking at the execution plans or anything besides renaming the index?

Comment: The execution plan is truly huge. I added the RECOMPILE option. Didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

These symptoms suggest a suboptimal cached query plan was being used due to parameter sniffing. Renaming the index voids the cached plan so a new one is generated upon next use which is most optimal for the query parameter values.

Parameter sniffing can be avoided going forward with a query hint like `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` or `OPTION(OPTIMZE FOR...)` as described in the [SQL Server documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query).

Comment: @StephenH.Anderson, did you try the `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` query hint (not to be confused with the `WITH RECOMPLE` stored procedure option)?

Comment: I'm running a stored procedure. So I added the WITH RECOMPILE to it. How can I exec the Stored Procedure adding the OPTION(RECOMPILE)  I tried exec my_sp NULL OPTION(RECOMPILE) but it gave an error (I'm in SQL 2005)

Comment: @StephenH.Anderson, I didn't notice you were using SQL 2005, which has unsupported for years. I don't believe the `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` query hint is available in that version. Another approach available in SQL 2005 is to use local variables instead of parameters in proc `WHERE` clauses. This is equivalent to optimizing for unknown parameter values, which results in a stable, albeit compromise, execution plan.